# How do I prevent that when the link in the code is clicked this link takes me to the page that makes reference

Tags: javascript

I found this code

```
<body>
<div id="div1">
What is 2+2?
</div>
<div id="div2">
<a href="answer.html" id="answer_link">Get the answer</a>
</div>
</body>
```

then the javascript

```
var d1 = document.getElementById("div1");
var a_link = document.getElementById("answer_link");
a_link.onclick = function() 
{
   d1.innerHTML = "That is easy, the answer is <strong>4</strong>!";
   return false;
};
```

so this code works because it changes the inner html in the div1
and doesn't load the page that the link makes reference but what if i want to use event listeners?
i write this

```
a_link.addEventListener( 'click', function(){
    d1.innerHTML = "That is easy, the answer is <strong>4</strong>!";
    return false;
}, false);
```

but it doesn't prevent the link to load the reference how can i use an event listener that works the same way that the little piece of code of above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `e.preventDefault()` for normal browsers and `event.returnValue` in older IE browsers:

```
aLink.addEventListener( 'click', function(e){
    d1.innerHTML = "That is easy, the answer is <strong>4</strong>!";
    if (e && e.preventDefault) {
        e.preventDefault();
    } else {
        window.event.returnValue = false;   // guess who - IE
    }
}, false);
```

Actually, older versions of IE don't even support `addEventListener()`, so the IE part of the code is only needed if you're using the same callback function with `attachEvent()` as you are with `addEventListener()` which I do.

Comment: :o that really works can you explain me please where comes from the e parameter? and thank you for your help :)

Comment: The e parameter is part of what addEventListener does when it triggers the event.  It's the event object.  Unfortunately, older versions of IE don't pass it.

Comment: ok thanks again jfriend00 I'm learning the language so this will help me a lot sorry if it was a dumb question thanks

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `prevenDefault`?  This may help you control the functionality of your click event.

Documentation here - https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/event.preventDefault

Also, in your code.  You switch from referencing the `<a>` tag with a var named `a_link` and a var named `aLink`.  Is this a typo or just a change in your implementation?

Answer (score 0):

Why does your anchor need a URL if you're not going to load it? Couldn't you just use "#" or something?

Comment: `#` for an href can still cause the page to jump.  It's best to block processing of the link as in the other answers.